# autoprefixer watch task configuration

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-watch

Currently I am using [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) inside of my `gulpfile.js`. However it **only works** with a watch task set up! This might be because I am not referencing the `return gulp.src('./site/css/*.css')` correctly.

Here is how autoprefixer explains how to set up a `autoprefixer` task

```
gulp.task('autoprefixer', function () {
    var postcss      = require('gulp-postcss');
    var sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
    var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

    return gulp.src('./src/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }) ]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});
```

Here is my `autoprefixer` task inside of my `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.watch('./site/css/main.css',['autoprefixer']);

gulp.task('autoprefixer',function () {
    var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
    var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
    var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

    return gulp.src('./site/css/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['> 1%','last 2 versions'] }) ]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/css'));
});
```

Link to the entire [gulpfile.js file](https://github.com/kapena/e-portfolio/blob/build/gulpfile.js) and the [repo](https://github.com/kapena/e-portfolio/tree/build) that I am working with.

Comment: How are you attempting to call the autoprefixer task if you're not using the watcher? Just `gulp autoprefixer`? Can you show us the commands you are expecting to work?

Comment: @TopherFangio well I was **expecting** it to just work without a watch. No watcher was used in the set up example for gulp usage. I guess the docs led me astray when I was setting this up.

Comment: Yeah, you still have to call the task from somewhere, and it looks like your gulpfile only setups the watcher as a dependency. The answer below is correct :-)

Comment: I am using the `watch` task because I wanted autoprefixer to run every time my `main.css` is changed. For example I make a small change to my main.css and `autoprefixer` runs. This is so I don't haft to make a direct call autoprefixer ever in the command line.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following... Are you saying you do or don't want to use autoprefixer as part of your watch task?

Comment: I don't want to use `autoprefixer` as part of my watch task. Just used your solution which works as I see that  `autoprefixer` is being fired in the styles task however my css is fired after `autoprefixer` runs therefore I do not get prefix's

Comment: Originally I thought `autoprefixer` would just work by me calling it within the `default` task...However that will not work as I need to have some kind of `watch` happing so `autoprefixer` knows what file to `watch` for changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your autoprefixer task directly by executing `gulp autoprefixer` from the cmd line or you can add it as a dependency of another task. Like this:

```
gulp.task('someTask', ['autoprefixer'], function () {
    //  Do stuff
});
```

See the relevant bit of documentation [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps).

**Edited**

The autoprefixer task will get executed BEFORE its dependent task does ('someTask' in my example), so be aware of your execution flow here.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: No problemo. Glad it helped

Comment: How can I get my `styles` task to execute b4 `autoprefixer` `gulp.task('styles',['autoprefixer'], function(){...
`

Comment: Can I just switch the tasks like this `gulp.task('autoprefixer',['styles'], function(){..`

Comment: Do it the other way around `gulp.task('autoprefixer', ['styles'], ...`

Comment: Getting the following Error: Task styles is not configured as a task on gulp.  If this is a submodule, you may need to use require('run-sequence').use(gulp).

Comment: Will you be available in 45 mins

Comment: it's pretty late here in FL. My suggestion is to think of your gulpfile in terms of which tasks you want to execute first, second, third, etc. See these tuts. Hopefully they help: [Tut 1](https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js) and [Tut 2](https://travismaynard.com/writing/getting-started-with-gulp)

Answer (score 0):

I came to a solution that archive's what I'm after. So I created a task called `prefixer` that contains a watch task that watches my `main.css` file for any changes.

```
// prefixer task containing a watch task for autoprefixer
gulp.task('prefixer',function(){
    gulp.watch('./site/css/main.css',['autoprefixer']);
});
```

I then pass the `prefixer` task to my `default` task

```
//default task
gulp.task('default',function(){
    // call runSequence to make sure our tasks are
    // perfromed in the correct order
    runSequence('scripts', 'styles','prefixer','sync');
});
```

The `prefixer` task contains the `watch` task that watches my `main.css` for changes. When changes occur in `main.css` the `autoprefixer` task is called upon.

```
[20:40:56] Starting 'styles'...

[20:40:57] Starting 'autoprefixer'...

[20:40:58] Finished 'autoprefixer' after 1.18 s

[20:40:58] Starting 'autoprefixer'...

[20:40:58] Finished 'autoprefixer' after 109 ms

[20:40:59] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Styles task complete
[BS] 1 file changed (main.min.css)
```